# Find SQL duplicate with specific condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, duplicates

I have problem with my postgres sql query.
I want to find duplicates with specific conditions.

| id | address_id | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 1 | A |
| 94 | 1 | A |
| 991 | 1 | A |
| 992 | 2 | A |
| 993 | 2 | A |

The conditions :
I want to find the duplicates based on address_id and they should have state 'A'

So I wrote query :

```
select count(*), g.address_id
            from tableName g
            where g.state = 'A'
            group by g.address_id
            having count(*)
                       > 1
```

When I want to get all values I just extended query to :

```
SELECT w.* from tableName w
    (select count(*), g.address_id
                from tableName g
                where g.state = 'A'
                group by g.address_id
                having count(*)
                           > 1) x on w.address_id = x.address_id
```

In output I get list of all duplicates. But I want to get duplicates with the highest id.

Based on my table i want to get output :

| id | address_id | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 991 | 1 | A |
| 993 | 2 | A |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way :

```
select tn.id,tn.address_id,tn.state
from tableName tn
inner join (select max(id) as id ,count(address_id) as nr_count
            from tableName
            where state='A'
            group by address_id
            ) as t1 on tn.id=t1.id
where   t1.nr_count >1;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1236dbae224f033fc50fc47960d73b4b)

You could use window function:

```
select max(id) as id ,address_id,state
from (
   SELECT id, address_id,state
        , count(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY address_id  ) AS cnt
   FROM   tableName
   where state='A'
   ) as t1
where cnt>1
group by address_id,state;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4b32d5f4affba8c4b1b353d58b7f44d2)